# Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader-v16/package.json'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vue-loader

i am new to vue.js, just coming from react.js. the problem i am facing with the vue loader didn't happened at first. but from the second time the app crashes from starting the server.

```
 npm run serve

> todo@0.1.0 serve /home/riyad/Desktop/todo_wedevs/todo
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader-v16/package.json'
Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader-v16/package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at api.chainWebpack.webpackConfig (/home/riyad/Desktop/todo_wedevs/todo/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js:114:23)
    at webpackChainFns.forEach.fn (/home/riyad/Desktop/todo_wedevs/todo/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:236:40)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Service.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (/home/riyad/Desktop/todo_wedevs/todo/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:236:26)
    at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (/home/riyad/Desktop/todo_wedevs/todo/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:240:48)
    at PluginAPI.resolveWebpackConfig (/home/riyad/Desktop/todo_wedevs/todo/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/PluginAPI.js:132:25)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! todo@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the todo@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/riyad/.npm/_logs/2020-08-20T11_40_44_196Z-debug.log
```

i have tried vue cli 3 and also 2..and installed different vue-loader..but the result is same
my babble.config.js file->

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"],
  plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "todo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "vue-loader": "^16.0.0-beta.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

the log->

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/riyad/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/riyad/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'serve' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v11.10.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
5 info lifecycle todo@0.1.0~preserve: todo@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle todo@0.1.0~serve: todo@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle todo@0.1.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle todo@0.1.0~serve: PATH: /home/riyad/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/riyad/Desktop/todo_wedevs/todo/node_modules/.bin:/home/riyad/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/bin:/home/riyad/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/riyad/.yarn/bin
9 verbose lifecycle todo@0.1.0~serve: CWD: /home/riyad/Desktop/todo_wedevs/todo
10 silly lifecycle todo@0.1.0~serve: Args: [ '-c', 'vue-cli-service serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle todo@0.1.0~serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle todo@0.1.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
13 verbose stack Error: todo@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/riyad/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/riyad/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:984:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
14 verbose pkgid todo@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/riyad/Desktop/todo_wedevs/todo
16 verbose Linux 5.6.19-2-MANJARO
17 verbose argv "/home/riyad/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/bin/node" "/home/riyad/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/bin/npm" "run" "serve"
18 verbose node v11.10.1
19 verbose npm  v6.7.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error todo@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the todo@0.1.0 serve script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

also do suggest me how to setup a project safely with vuex and vue-router

Comment: Actually downgrading the vue/cli from 4.5.6 to 3.0.1 worked..it downgraded the vue cli from 3 to 2...actually vue cli 3 is beta version....shouldn't use 3 right now...the comnand i used to downgrade
You simply need the specific version you want to install..in my case ->

npm install -g @vue/cli@3.0.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue create project - Cannot find module 'vue-loader-v16/package.json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483195/vue-create-project-cannot-find-module-vue-loader-v16-package-json)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483195/vue-create-project-cannot-find-module-vue-loader-v16-package-json
The solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/63485141/5249102 worked for me.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try to just install the pacakge to devDependencies:

`npm i --save-dev vue-loader-v16`

It helped me out.

With `babble.config.js` do you then mean `babel.config.js`, hehe?
Anyhow, I think your `babel.config.js` should just be like this:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"],
};
```

And for keeping your package.json more clean, you could make an `.eslintrc.js` file instead - just copy/paste the data from your `eslintConfig` key in `package.json`

Answer (score 23):

Update npm to version higher than 6.9 and do a
`npm i`, this should install the missing packages
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/pull/5718

`npm install npm@latest -g`(To update npm)

Comment: Worked, but I had to delete `node_modules` before `npm i`.

Comment: i aslo had to do `npm i`

Answer (score 5):

I solved it reinstalling the package. First you need to uninstall it

```
npm uninstall vue-loader-v16
```

Once uninstall completes, install it again

```
npm i vue-loader-v16
```

It seems obvious but it worked twice for me

Comment: it helps me a lot

Comment: faced same issue again, and found the same solution it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using laravel 9.x , laravel/ui , and use vue as scaffolding.
my issue solves as I upgrade the vue-loader to v15.9.8

```
npm i vue-loader@15.9.8 -D
```

edit :
here's my npm version

npm: '8.1.2',
node: '16.13.1',
v8: '9.4.146.24-node.14'

Answer (score 0):

For others, in case the other answers didn't work, I found my npm version was in need of an update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete node-modules folder from your project. Then you install npm again by using command

**npm i -g npm**

Then you need to serve your application  as

**npm run serve**

This might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are using a lower version ( < 6.9)  npm, so, are you using a lower nodejs ?

1. check your node version ( means your npm version)

`node -v`

2. install a newer node version

`nvm install 14.x.x`

3. nvm use 14.x.x

`npm -v`  => 6.14.x

Answer (score -1):

Actually downgrading the vue/cli from 4.5.6 to 3.0.1 worked..it downgraded the vue cli from 3 to 2...actually vue cli 3 is beta version....shouldn't use 3 right now...the comnand i used to downgrade
You simply need the specific version you want to install..in my case ->

npm install -g @vue/cli@3.0.1

Answer (score -1):

Edit App.js >> Go  to file path : src/component/App.vue

import this code

```
// code returned from the main loader for 'source.vue'

// import the <template> block
import render from 'source.vue?vue&type=template'
// import the <script> block
import script from 'source.vue?vue&type=script'
export * from 'source.vue?vue&type=script'
// import <style> blocks
import 'source.vue?vue&type=style&index=1'

script.render = render
export default script
```

and after run

```
npm run serve
```

i hope solve this error "Cannot find module 'vue-loader-v16/package.json'"